# How to validate android-manifest file?

Tags: android, eclipse, validation, android-manifest

recently I had an error, which was caused by a corrupted AndroidManifest.xml file. Is there any possibility out there to check for corrupted AndroidManifest.xml files from eclipse ?

Or is there a scheme file for the manifest to validate against it ?

The corruption was, that I forgot the "intent-filter" tag of an activity.  I got **no** error in eclipse or my app.

```
        <activity android:name=".ActivityExample" android:label="activity">     
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" /> 
        </activity>
```

Comment: Normally eclipse does that for you.

Comment: What kind of corruption was it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are asking for validation of the nodes then eclipse would do that for you....otherwise Cooktop is a good tool to validate xmls.

And if you want to validate as per the manifest schema then go through this link....
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: And I thought there is an awesome plugin/tool/xsd I just didn't know of. I hope the eclipse support will be better in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting that file and clean build that project.. i think it will work for you.

Comment: How does that answer help in validating the Manifest file?